# what is the value stored in void in C++

Tags: c++, c

What is the value that is stored in void()? Basically it is used before a function which doesnot return anything. But does simply void holds any value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Void is an incomplete type which, by definition, can't be an lvalue.
That means it can't get assigned a value.

So it also can't hold any value.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `void` for a return value means simply that there is nothing returned. So, there is no value, because there is just nothing at all.